# In a maven project how to execute java main or other command at compile time?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, ant, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I have a spring boot project, in this project I have a java main class that produce an md file for documentation.
Subsequently I must run a command on terminal that take this file as input and produce an html file.

I want that md and html files to be automatically generated any time that I edit java source codes.

Comment: What kind of main do you need to execute at compile time? For what purpose?

Comment: 1) I need to run a java main class when source code changes  2) I need to run a command on prompt when source code changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven is a building/lifecycle management tool.

You need to invoke the just built application, so the answer is: you cannot (and you don't).

You have to change approach.